# Can I configure a WCF service and consume a different on in the same application?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I'm trying to host on a website both the creation of a WCF service to send JSON data back to the client-side, as well as consume a different webservice used for cross application data exchange (it's a medical app, the data I need is hosted in an old ASMX webservice somewhere else)

My problem is the app is behind SSL, and basic authentication (which will go when we deploy to live), the service I'm consuming is over http and the rediculous amount of settings I need in the web.config are getting in each others way.

The web.config looks like this now

```
 <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AJAXEndpoint" >
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="MyNamespace.Service.ACSvc">
    <endpoint
     behaviorConfiguration="AJAXEndpoint"
     address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="UsernameWithTransport"
     contract="MyNamespace.Service.IACSvc">
    </endpoint>
 </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
    multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsAbbVieSoap">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="UsernameWithTransport">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://somewhere.else.com/externalservice.asmx"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsAbbVieSoap"
      contract="AbbvieService.wsAbbVieSoap" name="wsAbbVieSoap" />
</client>
```

Over various iterations, I've had my service working, but the external service not working or neither service working.

What I want

**My service** - HTTPS, Basic authentication, response in JSON
**External service** - HTTP, Anonymous, SOAP response

These services are not aware of each other and have nothing to do with each other. They're separate parts of the same website - one (mine) for my own clientside scripts, and the other (external) for me to call serverside for various business uses.

Any help appreciated

Comment: I won't try to debug your specific configuration but only say that you can absolutely consume other WCF services from a WCF service.

Comment: Sorry - might not have been completely clear, but it's a standard webforms website which is hosting this - the website both consumes and hosts it's own service, but these services have nothing to do with each other. They're just two parts of the application

Comment: That should be fine. In the past I have implemented IIS-hosted WCF web services that called out to other IIS hosted WCF web services with no issues, both with and without transport security.

Comment: Cool - I just wish WCF wasn't such a maze to configure :)

Comment: The built-in configuration tool (right-click on your .config in the IDE) might offer some help here.

Comment: I had no idea this existed - against which element in the .config do I do this? Will it help configure services? I have VS2013 btw

Comment: don't play around manually with web.config. Just do as required in WCF config tool. I consumed couple of services behind ssl inside a service, so it is more than doable in WCF.

Comment: Does anyone else thing that any configuration that needs a tool to create the configuration file is overcomplicated?